# How to use values from environment variable with kernel.json file

Tags: jupyter-kernel

I am trying to write a kernel.json file to support a new kernel that I am developing under Windows 11.  It is working fine with hardcoded paths to the executable kernel.  How can I use an environment variable to make the template kernel.json file system independent?  I have searched the web but not found a tip on how to do this.

For example, my current kernel.json file looks like this, and it works:

```
{
 "argv": ["java",
          "-cp",
          "C:/Me/MyProject/build/mykernel.jar",
          "ca.spatial.jupyter.IBeanshell",
              "{connection_file}"],
 "display_name": "BeanShell",
 "language": "beanshell"
}
```

I have tried without any success to include an environment variable using (where KERNEL_HOME is the environment variable containing the directory path):

```
{
 "argv": ["java",
          "-cp",
          "$KERNEL_HOME/mykernel.jar",
          "ca.spatial.jupyter.IBeanshell",
              "{connection_file}"],
 "display_name": "BeanShell",
 "language": "beanshell"
}
```

I also tried

```
os.path.expandvars('{KERNEL_HOME}/mykernel.jar')
```

I assume that there is some easy way to do this that I am missing.  I am not a pythonista so my apologies if this is a newbie question.